# Run commands in subshell

Tags: bash, shell, automation, sh, subshell

I want to automate one repeated task which I do regularly. That is creating rpm's for different architectures. To compile the code and create the rpm I need to set the project env. after setting the env I will create the rpm for the current architecture and again I should build rpms for other architecture by setting the env again.

I am trying to automate this process. The problem is once the env is set it I will be new shell so my script is not visible in the sub shell. How to automate this ??

This is what i tried.

```
cd $project_dir
setenv.sh x86      #creates new sub shell
make clean
make rpm
cp *rpm ~/

exit              #exit from the sub shell

setenv.sh x86_64     #creates new shell
make clean
make rpm
cp *.rpm ~/

exit
```

after setting the env to x86 , next commands are not getting executed.

Comment: What, exactly, does `setenv.sh` do? The next line of your script, `make clean`, won't run until `setenv.sh` returns, and it won't be running in any subshell; it will run the same shell that called `setenv.sh`.

Comment: setenv.sh will set the compilation environment in the new shell.

Comment: What does that mean? Are you just setting some environment variables? If so, those changes only last until `setenv.sh` exits, which is *before* `make clean` runs.

Answer (score 6):

You can force 2 parts to execute in sub-shells like this:

```
cd "$project_dir"

(. setenv.sh x86
make clean
make rpm
cp *rpm ~/)

(. setenv.sh x86_64
make clean
make rpm
cp *.rpm ~/)
```

Comment: I tried it. ( ) will create sub-shell but in that sub-shell setenv.sh will create one more shell. so those make commands are not visible in that shell.

Comment: well i tried it. but now I couldn't set the env. I am getting errors `setenv.sh: line 464: svnenvopts.source: No such file or directory`. what does that '.' do ?? I think i lost the path after doing that.

Comment: I don't have access to `setenv.sh` so I cant guess why that error showed up.

Comment: @DineshReddy setenv.sh will not create a subshell here. It is not being executed, it is being _sourced_ with `.`.